# Vertical SideMenu with toggle functionality in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a static website , which i need to develop using AngularJS.

How do I develop a vertical sideMenu with toggle functionality, 
with the sidemenu having menuItems->sub-menuItems-->Sub-sub-MenuItems?

Like this:

[image: screenshot]

Below is my html code?

How do i convert this into sidebar directive in angularjs so that i can reuse it?

```
<li class="active ">
            <a href="javascript:;">
            <i class="fa fa-medkit"></i>
            <span class="title">Health and Safety</span>
            <span class="arrow "></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">

                 <li class=" ">
                    <a href="javascript:;"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                     H & S Dashboard  
                    <span class="arrow "></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="javascript:;"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    HIRA<span class="arrow "></span>
                     </a>
                     <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#/hira-list" > 
                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                            HIRA List

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#/hira-intimation">  
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                            HIRA Creation
                             </a>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="javascript:;" > 
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                         Accident
                    <span class="arrow "></span>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#/accident-list" > 
                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                            Accident List

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#/accident-intimation">  
                            <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>
                            Intimation
                             </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#/accident-detailed-report">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-md"></i>
                            Detailed Report</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#/accident-rcp"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                            RCA & CAPA
                             </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="javascript:;">  
                    <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>
                     Unsafe Action
                    <span class="arrow "></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#/unsafe-action-list"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                             Unsafe Action List
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#/unsafe-action-intimation">  
                            <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>
                                Intimation
                             </a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- <li class=" ">
                            <a href="javascript:;"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                RCA & CAPA
                             </a>
                        </li> -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="active">
                    <a href="javascript:;">  
                    <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>
                     Unsafe Condition
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#/unsafe-condition-list"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                            Unsafe Conditon List

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#/unsafe-condition-intimation">  
                            <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>
                                Intimation
                             </a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- <li class=" ">
                            <a href="javascript:;"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                RCA & CAPA
                             </a>
                        </li> -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="javascript:;"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                     Near Miss 
                    <span class="arrow "></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class=" ">
                            <a href="#/near-miss-list" > 
                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                                Near Miss List

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#/near-miss-intimation">  
                            <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>
                                Intimation
                             </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" ">
                            <a href="javascript:;"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                RCA & CAPA
                             </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=" ">
                    <a href="javascript:;">  
                        <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>
                        Suggestion
                        <span class="arrow "></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="javascript:;" > 
                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                            Suggestion List

                        </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="javascript:;">  
                                <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>
                                Intimation
                             </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" ">
                            <a href="javascript:;"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                             Status
                             </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="">
                    <a href="javascript:;">  
                        <i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i>
                        Monitor & Measures
                        <span class="arrow "></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        *open close functionality in sidebar*
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Report OP to @wipro for asking people to do his office work 